# Check for Duplicates in one Column (and removes them) and sums up values in another Column (writing results into first row)

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, sum

I have a macro which automatically checks for duplicates (customer number) in Column K (Picture 1) and removes them after pasting data from an other database and works perfectly. But now I need to sum up the values in Column AE (at the moment it just keeps the first row and deletes the others) and write the result in the  first row.

[image: Picture1]

Note: I have a lot of data that I don´t need but can´t avoid to copy, so I minimized all the columns I don´t need. And there are some empty Columns, including Column A (Picutre 2)

[image: Picture2]

The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
  Dim Rng As Range
  Set Rng = Range("A4:AE200")

  Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 11), Header:=xlNo
    Columns("A:AE").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Can you please help me upgrade my code to sum up the Values in AE? Thank you!

Comment: try this Range("AE201").Formula = "=sum(AE1:AE200)"

Comment: @virxen Thank you for you quick response! I am kinda new to coding, can you be a little more specific please :)

Comment: in cell AE201 you add the formula to sum the cells from AE1 to AE200 like you do in excel to sum a column manually

Comment: It not that what I am looking for, but thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Remove Duplicates

- I think it's a bad idea to do it using an event. It will trigger the event anytime you make a change in any cell. I have restricted it to run just for a change in the range `K4:K1048576` but I still don't like it.
- I would prefer to use a button for it or run it at the same time (right after of course) I copy the data (via code) with the signature `Sub DoppelteEntfernen(ByVal ws As Worksheet)`.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    DoppelteEntfernen Target
End Sub
```

**Manual Call (Near the Main Code)**

```vb
Sub Test()
    DoppelteEntfernen Sheet1.Range("K4") ' Target
End Sub
```

[image]

**The Main Code (Standard Module e.g. `Module1`)**

- This usually belongs in a standard module so you can call it without qualifying it with a module.

```vb
Sub DoppelteEntfernen(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Doppelte Entfernen"
    
    ' Start an error-handling routine.
    
    Dim Success As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError
     
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "A4"
    Const UNIQUE_COLUMN As Long = 11 ' K
    Dim SumupColumns(): SumupColumns = VBA.Array(15, 31) ' O, AE
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    
    ' Check if there was a change in the unique column.
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL).EntireRow.Columns(UNIQUE_COLUMN)
        Set rg = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
        
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(rg, Target)
    
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim sUpper As Long: sUpper = UBound(SumupColumns)

    Dim srg As Range
    
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set srg = ws.Range(FIRST_CELL, .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
    End With
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to an array.
    
    Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value

    ' Write the unique values from the unique column of the array and their rows
    ' to a dictionary while writing the unique data to the top of the array.
    ' All columns are written for each unique item but only the sumup-columns
    ' are summed up for an existing item.

    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim uVal, sr As Long
    
    ' The source data stays intact until the first duplicate is found.
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        uVal = Data(sr, UNIQUE_COLUMN)
        If dict.Exists(uVal) Then Exit For
        dict(uVal) = sr
    Next sr
    
    ' Check if no duplicates.
    If sr > srCount Then
        MsgBox "No duplicates found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dr As Long: dr = sr - 1
    
    Dim wr As Long, wc As Long, c As Long
    
    ' Write after first duplicate was found.
    For sr = sr To srCount
        uVal = Data(sr, UNIQUE_COLUMN)
        If dict.Exists(uVal) Then ' exists; write sum-up columns
            wr = dict(uVal)
            For c = 0 To sUpper
                wc = SumupColumns(c)
                Data(wr, wc) = Data(wr, wc) + Data(sr, wc)
            Next c
        Else ' doesn't exist; write all columns
            dr = dr + 1
            dict(uVal) = dr
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Write the data from the top of the array back to the range
    ' and clear its excessive rows below.
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With srg.Resize(dr)
        .Value = Data
        .Resize(srCount - dr).Offset(dr).Clear
    End With
    
    Success = True
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop if error ahead
        ' Make sure to enable events!!!
        If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
        ' Inform.
        If Success Then
            MsgBox "Duplicates removed.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
' Continue error-handling routine.
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I will test the code now, but is it possible so let it be as an event? Because it´s menat to updated itself every time, because i will copy that data to another sheet and then delete the data... so i would like it to stay automated...

Comment: i tested the code, it works fine, but i just had to press the button I created once and after that it worked automatically. is that intended? I mean if just didn´t need the button it would be perfect :D 
and i don´t need the message boxes, because it´s kinda a data export/import tool, so the less clicks i need and the more things do automatically the better :)

Comment: P.S and i dont need to sum up column O, so i just need to delete "15"?
Dim SumupColumns(): SumupColumns = VBA.Array(15, 31)

Comment: You don't need a button, it always works automatically as soon as you change something in `K4:K1048576`. Sorry, I exposed you to so much out-commenting or deleting.

Comment: Oh, I didn´t test that yet, but will do now. You don´t need to apologize, I am thankful you invested your so much time into my problem! Thanks again, this helps me a lot :)

Comment: You sir are truly a genius! It works like a charm :)
The only thing is that I get a 0 at the end of Column AE ( I can´t copy a screenshot here...). Is it possible to get rid of that 0?